# What is the correct method in where_in?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

i want to get data using where in condition

my code is below

```
SELECT `cuc_UserCardsDetail`.*, `cuc_CreditCardType`.`varValidName`
FROM (`cuc_UserCardsDetail`)
JOIN `cuc_CreditCardType` ON `cuc_CreditCardType`.`intGlCode` = 
`cuc_UserCardsDetail`.`fk_CardTypeGlCode`
WHERE `cuc_UserCardsDetail`.`intGlCode` IN ('10,29') 
AND `chrAccountType` =  'M'
ORDER BY `dtCreateDate` desc
```

now I have resulted with one row actually in my table there is two-row with related id

i think problem is In('10,29') but i want like ('10','29') or (10,29) how can i do in codeigitor?

**i want (10,29) or ('10','29') in where in ..**

Comment: pass separate element in `IN` as `IN ('10','29')`, Also this is not and codeigniter query, its simple `mysql` query, if you are using `codeigniter`, you should use `active query builder`

Comment: but how can i do in codeignitor query? i pass in parameter like 10,29

Comment: You should be passing an _array_ containing those two values to the where_in method.

Answer (score 4):

In CI query builder use

```
$id= array('10', '20'); # or direct assing your input params
$this->db->where_in('column_name', $id);
```

Read [Looking for Specific Data - Codeigniter.com](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data)

Answer (score 2):

Method chaining will accept array in `where_in`

```
$intGlCode = array(10, 29);
$this->db->select('`cuc_UserCardsDetail`.*, `cuc_CreditCardType`.`varValidName`');
$this->db->from('cuc_UserCardsDetail');
$this->db->join('cuc_CreditCardType','cuc_CreditCardType.intGlCode = 
cuc_UserCardsDetail.fk_CardTypeGlCode');
$this->db->where('chrAccountType','M');
$this->db->where_in('cuc_UserCardsDetail.intGlCode',$intGlCode);
$this->db->order_by('dtCreateDate','DESC');
$data = $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

Comment: i tried your code but in result its give me WHERE `intGlCode` IN ('10,29')  . so only one row data found.

Comment: ('10,29') will not work here, try this `array(10,29)`

Answer (score 1):

Your query look something like

you have to define column `chrAccountType` from which table, here i assume it from **cuc_UserCardsDetail**

```
$this->db->select('ud.*, cc.varValidName');
$this->db->where_in('ud.intGlCode', ['10','29']);
$this->db->where('ud.chrAccountType', 'M');
$this->db->order_by('dtCreateDate', 'desc');
$this->db->join('cuc_CreditCardType cc', 'cc.intGlCode = ud.fk_CardTypeGlCode');
$data = $this->db->get('cuc_UserCardsDetail ud')->result_array();



 print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

where_in() function just in the case of array of data.

```
$ids = array();
$this->db->where_in('id', $ids);
```